# Шаблон меню с переходом по ссылкам

Tags: веб-программирование, php, html, javascript

У нас есть шаблон главной страницы. Он тут приведен для наглядности  (index.tpl)

Есть index.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$f1="index.tpl";
if (!file_exists($f1)) {
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo "<center>
<br><br>
<h1>нет шаблона!</h1>

</center>";

exit;
}
$f = fopen($f1,"r"); 
$site = fread($f, filesize ($f1)); 
fclose ($f);
require_once "news.php";
$site=str_replace('{news}',$news,$site);
echo "{$site}";
exit;
?>
```

Как организовать меню - переход по ссылкам. Чтоб шаблон оставался тот же, а содержимое менялось? + неплохо было бы динамики добавить, те возможность добавления элементов меню и следовательно нового содержимого. Сколько инт не копал - везде непонятно написано.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$f1="index.tpl";
if (!file_exists($f1)) {
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo "<center>
<br><br>
<h1>нет шаблона!</h1>
</center>";
exit;
}

$menu = '<a href="?mode=ololo">OLOLOLO</a><br>
<a href="?mode=trololo">TROLOLOLO</a>';
if($_GET['mode']=='ololo'){
$content = "LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOL";
}
elseif($_GET['mode']=='trololo'){
$content = "BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA";
}
else{
require_once "news.php";
$content=$news;
}
$site=str_replace(array('{content}','{menu}'),
array($content,$menu),
file_get_contents("index.tpl"));
echo $site;
exit;
?>
```

Comment: <a href="?mode=trololo">TROLOLOLO</a>' вот например не могу понять что за ?mode= почему именно так?

Comment: mode - $_GET переменная, которую мы обрабатываем и взависимости от ее содержимого отображаем тот или иной контентю

Comment: new_russian_man, потому что перед созданием сайта удостойтесь прочитать хотя-бы банальную документацию по php (php.su/net вам в помощь)

Answer (score 0):

Целесообразно использовать iframe. Теорчасть:

Общий вид: 2 панели стыкующиеся по фронтам.

1. Страница index.php содержит меню которое необходимо разместить как блок слева. Справа мы размещаем iframe с параметрами noborder и т.д. по желанию
2. Ставим получение параметра (например file), т.е. `switch($_GET['file']){case` 'log':$file='log.php' break;}
3. Ставим iframe'у `src="<?php echo("$file") ?>"`
4. Для начала радуемся. Используя jquery или смекалку можно обозначать отмеченый пункт меню. и т.д. Все зависит от сообразительности и умений и предпочтений. Так я делал админку для своей cms. Есть вопросы - пишите на мыло.

Comment: Использовать iframe О_О для смены контента О_О

Что за чушь, сударь? Не путайте пожалуйста людей.

Comment: а почему бы и нет? все приходит с опытом, лучше начать с более простого, не?

Comment: я думаю нет ,сравне рисованию в паинте вместо фотошопа.
Если сайт пишется на php то лучше использовать его(php).
Не то чтобы ваш вариант не имеет права на существование, просто тогда уж лучше юзать для каждого раздела отдельный html файлик.